# python virtual environment .exe file usage

Tags: python, virtualenv

What is the difference between running a script by first sourcing:

```
source /venv/bin/activate
python script.py
```

and running the script with the actual python exe?

```
/venv/bin/python script.py
```

do these two commands always do the same thing? The problem that I am seeing is that if script.py calls other python scripts, and the settings and packages that are in venv don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how does `script.py` runs other scripts. If it uses [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable), that is the current python, `/venv/bin/python` then both commands are equivalent.

If `script.py` runs other scripts using shell (`os.system`, `subprocess`, etc) then the first one is the preferred form because it sets `$PATH` for all subprocesses so that all python scripts use the same virtual environment.

And the final note. If some script(s) being run from `script.py` have fixed shebang like `#!/usr/bin/python` those scripts will not be run in your virtual environment regardless of the 1st or 2nd way you run `script.py`.